# Перебор фотографий, vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Мне нужно, чтобы при добавление фотографии, отображалось сразу же фотография которую добавили. То есть добавили одну фотографию, она отобразилась, добавили вторую - она отобразилась следующая и т.д.
Вот как делал я:

```
  <input type="file" multiple class="form-control" @change="fieldChange">
```

vue:

```
    fieldChange(e){

                        let selectedFiles=e.target.files;

                        for(let i=0;i<selectedFiles.length;i++){
                            this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
                        }

                        for(let i=0;i<this.attachments.length;i++){
                           var myIt = this.attachments[i];
                        }

                        this.createImages(myIt);
                    },

    createImages(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (e) => {
                        this.images = e.target.result;
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                },
```

Тут отображение фото:

```
  <img class="img-responsive" :src="images" >
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что я загружаю фотографию, высвечивается первая, потом снова, загружаю вторую - и первая превращается во вторую фотографию, то есть все фотографии становятся последней. 
Помогите пожалуйста, как можно грамотнее переделать, чтобы высвечивались все загруженные фотографии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отобразить список изображений, необходимо этот список записать, например, в массиве.

Для отображения списка изображений используется цикл `v-for`.

Пример реализации:

```js
var container = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      images: [],
      attachments: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fieldChange(e) {
      let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        this.attachments.push(selectedFiles[i]);
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
        var myIt = this.attachments[i];
      }
      this.createImages(myIt);
    },
    createImages(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.images.push(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.runtime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
  <input type="file" multiple class="form-control" @change="fieldChange">
  <img v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="`image-${index}`" class="img-responsive" :src="image">
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/57xfesja/

Comment: Спасибо. Еще небольшой вопрос, как сделать чтобы можно было к примеру загружать по 3-4 фотографии сразу, то там выделяю, и грузит одну случайную

Comment: Вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/57xfesja/2/ ? Нужно только убрать определение последней выбранной фотографии ( `var myIt = this.attachments[i]; ` ), и будет показываться сразу все фотографии, которые были выбраны.